# Get property of external filter in controller onCreate() method of the Yii framework

Tags: php, frameworks, filter, yii, oncreate

I have controller which uses external filter coded in separate class.
This filter perform verification before execute `onCreate()` method of the controller.
But I need get property of this filter object after filter executed for create operation.

How can I get property of external filter in `onCreate()` method of the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In filter method `preFilter` you have access to controller who owns it via `$filterChain->controller`. This means that you can set any controller's property you need and use it in `onCreate` controller method.

I hope this helps.